# How can I create a subclass UIViewControllerDebug with UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I create a custom superclass UIControllerDebug with superclass UIController.

And I use this class with some other subclass. It crash with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewControllerDebug", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Main in Main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewControllerDebug", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Main in Main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what haapened ?

code here:
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIViewControllerDebug : UIViewController
@end
```

.m

```
#import "UIViewControllerDebug.h"
@implementation UIViewControllerDebug
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    Output(@"[v]%@ touchesBegan",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    Output(@"[v]%@ touchesBegan",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    Output(@"[v]%@ touchesBegan",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you do not have an `@implementation` of `UIViewControllerDebug` in your source code, or the file containing the `@implementation` of `UIViewControllerDebug` is not listed in the “Compile Sources” section of the “Build Phases” tab of your target.

Comment: I deal as others. but only UIView and UIViewController have the problem.

Comment: What does “I deal as others” mean?

Comment: I just say it works well inherit with NSObject . but not with UIViewController.